# How can I get file name from request.FILE in Django?

Tags: python, django, image-uploading

I tried this code for saving images. It saves the image at the given path, but does not get the file name. How can I get it?

```
@csrf_exempt
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if 'filename'  in request.FILES:
        filename = request.FILES['filename'].name
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_profileform/')
    else:

        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('user_profile.html', {'form': form })

def handle_uploaded_file(f):

    destination = open('media/filename', 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks(): 
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

Comment: And what does this line give to you `filename = request.FILES['filename'].name`?

Comment: `handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])` looks like it should be `handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['filename'])`. Also it doesn't look like you are doing anything with the `filename = request.FILES['filename'].name`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to reuse the filename to save the file, you can try:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    filename = f.name  # get the name here
    destination = open('media/'+filename, 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks(): 
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

In your `upload_file` view, there are something wrong too:

```
@csrf_exempt
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if 'filename'  in request.FILES:
        # filename = request.FILES['filename'].name  # remove this line, you don't need it
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['filename']) # should be filename here
    #.... your code ....
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an encoding error. Is your POST encoded as UTF-8? That means in the HTML there is something like:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```